# (in Gnome) KTorrent "open folder" starts Banshee

Tags: 11.10, ktorrent

KTorrent once used to ask me what program to use (and I could tell it to use Nautilus), but now it only ever opens Banshee...which is less than useful.

Can anyone tell me how to explain to its tiny KDE brain that I want to use Nautilus to browse a folder?

**Edit:** after belatedly checking `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` it did only list banshee and vlc for `inode/directory`, though why this is so is a mystery.  After changing the setting KTorrent then once again asked me for a choice of program and I could check the ‘remember this choice’ checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tiny KDE brain uses the xdg-open standard for determining which application to open for a specific mimetype.

In the GNOME system settings, I think it can be found under Details>Default Applications, but I don't have a GNOME install to verify.

If you have KDE System Settings installed (the `systemsettings` package), then you can go to Workspace Appearance and Behavior->Default Applications->File Manager, then find nautilus and select it.

To do it manually, the file to modify is `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.  Content of the file should be:

```
[Added Associations]
inode/directory=nautilus-2.desktop;
```

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04 (non-kde), I worked this out by installing `systemsettings` and modifying the association from there